# Windows Shell Experience Host not working for only one Domain User

Tags: windows-server-2016

Hello fellow SysAdmins,

I have an extremely high usage server that's causing issues for only one domain user. Whenever he logs in he gets the old "Shell Experience Host has stopped working" error. The symptom is pretty obvious, sihost.exe fails to start on his profile, works on everyone elses profile.

Googling this provides a couple useless suggestions like sfc /scannow. Re-installing the C++ redistributable packages, which would be worth a shot if it was **all** users, but this only **one** user. I intend to try deleting his profile later on today.

Has anyone ever run into this where only one domain user has this problem?

Some background information, at least 20 users are logged into this server around the clock. Potentially up to forty users at a time. Over 100 unique profiles are loaded. Rebooting would be incredibly difficult to schedule but if it's required I'm open to the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all other users can log in successfully, this strongly points to a damaged user profile.

Just delete it (after backing it up, of course, the user could have something important in there).

---

Caveat: ***NEVER*** manually delete the user profile folder (`C:\Users\username`) (*); that would lead only to worse problems, due to lingering info about the profile remaining in the Registry. If you need to delete a user profile, do it from the advanced system properties or use [proper tools](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/).

(*) Unless you know *exactly* what else needs cleaning.

Comment: Yup that was it. Unfortunately someone else went full nuclear option and deleted their domain account. Prior to that I had deleted the registry keys and gone through advanced systems settings to clear it out.